# Selecting Multiple dates in a DateTimePicker in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, datetimepicker

Is there anyway i can select multiple dates in a Date Time Picker in Vb.net?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? pls explain the scenario. BTW Its not possible to pick two dates at a time.

Comment: I am trying to get the collection of dates and want to use it for making salaries for employees. I found MonthCalendar control which seems to be perfect for this purpose but i cant find the option (method, property) to get the selectedDates and then use them. Any comments on that?

Answer (score 3):

Use BoldedDates Property in your month calendar to get the array of DateTime objects. You can use this to get your collection and finally clear the bold dates after storing it, so that it can be reused.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. How can i use it? I mean i want to click a date so that it gets bold and then after all the desired dates are selected, i want to add them to BoldedDates array by clicking a button. I want to show the selection to the user as well in MonthCalendar so that he knows the dates he is selecting.

Answer (score 2):

> Selecting Multiple dates in a DateTimePicker in vb.net?

If you want to select a range of dates using a DateTimePicker, then the best way if probably two `DateTimePicker` controls a from date and a to date.

You can then change the date of the opposite control when the first date is picked to make sure the FromDate is before the ToDate and vice versa

> I found MonthCalendar control which seems to be perfect for this purpose but i cant find the option (method, property) to get the selectedDates and then use them.

If you want to use a `MonthCalendar` control you can specify a `MaximumSelectionCount` property and then the user can select dates by clicking on one and shift-clicking on another date

You can retrieve the dates the user selected by using the `SelectionRange`, or `SelectionStart` and `SelectionEnd` properties

> How about if i want to select random dates, like 4th, 6th, 10th Feb.

This is more complex. A suggestion - you could use the `BoldedDates` array of the `MonthCalendar` and when a user clicks on a day, you bold it. You can then read the array after they have finished their selection? Maybe someone else has a suggestion for this?

Comment: How about if i want to select random dates, like 4th, 6th, 10th Feb. As SelectionRange.Start and SelectionRange.End will give the starting and ending date and not the selected dates. Furthermore in MonthCalendar you can select concurrent dates and not random selection.

Answer (score 2):

```
Private listDates As List(Of DateTime)
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    'Suppose that you have the following list of dates below
    listDates = New List(Of DateTime)()
    listDates.Add(DateTime.Now)
    listDates.Add("12/22/2012")
    listDates.Add(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10))
End Sub
Protected Sub Calendar1_DayRender(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DayRenderEventArgs) Handles Calendar1.DayRender
    'Set Default properties
    e.Day.IsSelectable = False
    e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray
    'Now loop through the list of dates and make it
    'Selectable
    For Each d As DateTime In listDates
        Calendar1.SelectedDates.Add(d)
        If e.Day.IsSelected Then
            e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green
            e.Day.IsSelectable = True
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Protected Sub Calendar1_SelectionChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Calendar1.SelectionChanged
    'Print the selected date
    Response.Write("You have selected: " & Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString())
End Sub
```

i found it, and try. it work,
original source from [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/dotNETvinz/archive/2010/02/01/highlight-multiple-dates-in-calendar-and-make-it-selectable.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this inside the existing `DateTimePicker` control.

The best alternative solution will depend on your specific situation. What's the context? If you're expecting the user to pick dates which are close together (and the range isn't too big) a reasonably simple solution is to use another control which will allow multiselect on a list.

For example a `CheckedListBox` or `DataGridView`.

Then populate it with a list of dates. In effect offering the user a picklist of dates.